# VS Package Extension to add a new project type to the new projects options window

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions, vs-extensibility, vspackage, new-project

I woulkd like to create a Visual Studio extension. I chose the Package option since the AddIn option will be deprecated from Visual Studio 2013 and above.

So i installed Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio SDK 2012, and created a new VS Package project.

Now, I want my package to enable the user to create a new type of project. i.e: I want to extend the right click->new project options to contain a new model of project, which will be a standard Visual C++ project, with some additional configurations, links, references and etc.

I googled a lot, but found nothing.

Does any of you have an idea about this target?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think the `Visual Studio Template Schema Reference` contains all information you need to create custom project templates; see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwkxbww4.aspx

You can derive a project template from an existing project, which might be the way to go, since it creates a valid template that only needs some customizing. A template export can be done by using the `Export Template` command found in the `File` menu.

The template wizard will create a `ZIP` file containing the template manifest and all referenced files; just extract the archive and customize it in the way you want it (add/remove files, change information like name and description in the manifest). Once you´ve your customized template, create a new `VISX` package project and add the template `ZIP` file to it (using `Add Existing Item` command).

The last step will be to add an `Asset` to the `VISX` manifest. Open the `source.extension.vsixmanifest` file in the `VSIX` designer, goto the `Assets` tab and click the `New` button; this will open a dialog to setup the asset... choose `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectTemplate` as the type - and `File on filesystem` as the source. This will allow you to pick the previously added `ZIP` file. Build the package  - and you´re done.

Comment: Hi @Matze, thanks for your response! I will explain more detailed what I have to do: I'ld like to have an extension, which: enables the user to create a new project from a new type(i.e.: from new project template, with specific dependencies and other definitions). on the new project creation I'ld like to import an existing solution  and locate the new project in a specific folder of this solution. Do you know about a way to write code like this on creation of a new project of the new template? Do I have any event/other handler on the template code,or in the whole package code, which I can use?

Comment: A wizard implementation might be suitable; see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171411.aspx and: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx. I would suggest to open another question, since it is a complete different problem...

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744216/vs-extension-which-declares-a-new-project-template-and-locate-the-generated-proj

Comment: Hi @Matze, I tried using the template wizard. It really has the RunStarted methode which is called on the project creation, but there are no many options there... I'm trying to change the new project destination directory and solution, but didn't succeed. I'ld like to know:if I'll return to the simple template+package option, Don't I have any way to write code which will be called on the project creation and will be able to chenge the project parent solution and etc.? I think that in the future I'll need more functionality that is available only in the package option, so I prefer to return...