# VS Extension which declares a new project template and locate the generated project in a specific location of an imported tree

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility

I would like to create a Visual Studio extension.

I installed Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio SDK 2012.

Now, I want my extension to create a new project template, and then to enable the user to create a new project of the new generated type. i.e: I would like that once the user will open VS and will click on "add new project", he will have a new project type in the list of the regular templates. The template will be a standard C project, with some additinal dependencies, some changes in the.vcxproj file, in the compiling configurations and more.

In additinal, I want that on the project creation, my extension will import an existiong solution from my computer to be the current VS solution, and that the new project will be added to a specific folder in that solution.
Is there any way to write code which is doing the described above, on the creation of a new project of the new template? Do I have any event/other handler on the template code, or in the package code, which I can use?

I googled tons, but I really don't know what is the best way I can do it...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Best place to start is to stop assuming you have to write an extension.  Start with an existing template, make changes to the settings and simply use File + Export Template to create a new project template.  Project property sheets are also quite powerful.  If you still think you need to write an extension then you'll find *lots* of documentation in MSDN.  Only ask answerable questions at SO, nobody is going to write the Missing Manual for you, particularly when it isn't missing.